# Not getting the data from nspropertylistserialisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, file, cocoa-touch

Not getting the data to the array variable

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Employees.plist"];

NSData *datas = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *err;
NSMutableArray *array = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:datas
                                                         mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                   format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                         errorDescription:&err];
```

Anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Try printing out the path to the console and making sure its being correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

This should be throwing a compiler error. You're not supposed to pass a format value to the format arg. You're supposed to pass a pointer to a variable of type `NSPropertyListFormat` - this variable will be filled in with the actual format once the plist is deserialized. In any case, you're better off just using `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path]` instead of using NSPropertyListSerialization.